# Android: Закрыть и сделать недоступным меню

Tags: android, меню

**Android**
У меня есть меню внутри DrawerLayout

```
    <com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
     android:id="@+id/nav_view"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
     android:layout_gravity="end"
     android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
     app:menu="@menu/right_menu" />
```

Мне надо его закрыть и предотвратить открытие (сделать так, чтобы он не открывался)
Пробовал так:

> NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(binding.navView, navController)

не помогло

Answer (score 0):

Не достаточно рейтинга, написал бы комментарий. :)
Мне пришел в голову вариант с использованием
[перехвата касания](https://developer.android.com/training/gestures/viewgroup)
И просто возвращать из него true, чтобы событие дальше не шло
для закрытия NavigationView придется делать свою разметку и управлять ей. Могу ошибаться.

Если надо предотвратить открытие DrawerLayout то

```
setDrawerLockMode(DrawerLayout.LOCK_MODE_LOCKED_CLOSED)
```

Comment: Давай двигаться по порядку: сначала надо закрыть "drawer"

Comment: binding.drawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.END, true)
binding.drawerLayout.closeDrawer(binding.navView)

Comment: binding.drawerLayout.closeDrawers()

Comment: ^^ эти варианты не срабатывают

Comment: closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START)